# Want to convert SAS code using proc nlmixed to R code using nlme

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

The question is similar to the one in the following post:

"
[troubles converting proc nlmixed (SAS) to nlme (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155086/troubles-converting-proc-nlmixed-sas-to-nlme-r)
"

Comment: What R code have you attempted?

Comment: Useful edit would be to create a sample data set in SAS, run your analysis (no more than 20 records, say), show the results, and then we'd know what the target we were shooting for was (especially if you give us the sample data set too). In my experience very few ppl here have SAS licenses compared to R licenses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like a mixed model at all -- what is the random effect?  It looks like a slightly unusual generalized linear model:  I would think this would do it.

```
glm((1-p)~d1+d2+d3+d4-1,family=binomial(link="log"))
```

(you'll have to flip the sign of the parameters yourself).

[Tiwari et al. 2006](http://accstr.ufl.edu/accstr-resources/publications/Tiwari_et_al_2006_MEPS.pdf) fit a model of this type.

R equivalent:

```
dd <- read.table("sas_vals.txt",header=TRUE,na.string=".")
g1 <- glm((1-Y)~d1+d2+d3+d4-1,family=binomial(link="log"),data=dd,
    start=rep(-0.1,4))
```

This is a bit difficult, probably in part because of the tiny data set (I assume this is a subset of the real data -- fitting 4 parameters to 21 binary observations would be a very bad idea ...)

Or:

```
library("bbmle")
g2 <- mle2(Y~dbinom(prob=1-exp(-p),size=1),
           parameters=list(p~d1+d2+d3+d4-1),
           start=list(p=0.1),
           data=dd)
```

The log-likelihoods suggest that the `mle2` fit is better, and refitting the `glm` fit with those starting values works better:

```
g3 <- update(g1,start=-coef(g2))
g4 <- mle2(Y~dbinom(prob=1-(exp(-p)^exp(b*Treat)),size=1),
           parameters=list(p~d1+d2+d3+d4-1),
           start=list(p=0.1,b=0),
           data=dd)
summary(g4)
##      Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(z)
## p.d1 0.106163   0.088805  1.1955 0.2319
## p.d2 0.241029   0.178263  1.3521 0.1763
## p.d3 0.105970   0.113455  0.9340 0.3503
## p.d4 0.179232   0.189951  0.9436 0.3454
## b    0.559624   0.740500  0.7557 0.4498
```

This seems to match the SAS results pretty well.

Comment: that's harder -- I think you won't easily find an R package that allows for generalized nonlinear mixed models.  You might have to go to a system like AD Model Builder.  You could ask as a separate question, or ask on `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` ...